# how to make the drop down list to be visible for certain user only in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, role

i am trying to make the drop down list to be visible for certain user only. for example for user =1 i want the drop down list to be visible and for user = 2 i don't want the drop down list to be visible.

i have tried this.

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 1) || 
     Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 2 || 
     Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 4)
        {
            ddlSpecialist.Visible = true;

            ddlSpecialist.DataSource = Lundbeck.Web.BusinessLogic.FrequencyReport.GetFrequencyReportbySpecialistList();
            ddlSpecialist.DataTextField = "Repcode";
            ddlSpecialist.DataValueField = "Repcode";
            ddlSpecialist.DataBind();
            ddlSpecialist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
            ddlSpecialist.SelectedValue = "0";

            if (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 3)
            {
                ddlSpecialist.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

i dont get the result that i want when i do this. why is that?? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want it to be visible for user 2, why are you setting it to visible when UserGroupId is 2?: `Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 2`

Comment: i think you must go through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx to know how the if else statement works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do please see you if condition you are checking if user==1 || user==2 || user==4
than you are showing dropdownlist and in same if condition you are checking if user==3 how is this possible if user==1 || user==2 || user==4 than it cannot be ==3 change your code like this.

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 1) || 
 Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 2 || 
 Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 4)
    {
        ddlSpecialist.Visible = true;

        ddlSpecialist.DataSource = Lundbeck.Web.BusinessLogic.FrequencyReport.GetFrequencyReportbySpecialistList();
        ddlSpecialist.DataTextField = "Repcode";
        ddlSpecialist.DataValueField = "Repcode";
        ddlSpecialist.DataBind();
        ddlSpecialist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "0"));
        ddlSpecialist.SelectedValue = "0";


    }
  else if (Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroupId"]) == 3)
        {
            ddlSpecialist.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: thank you @mairaj it worked. yea i was my mistake putting it visible to user = 2. my mistake. thanks anyways.